# D3 Keeps on Rerendering even with .exit().remove() in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I want to refresh the gauge whenever the window resizes because for some reason the gauge created in d3 get's clipped on small screens when manually resized but if you refresh on the same smaller screen, it positions nicely. This lead me to the conclusion that I need to redraw the d3 component on screen resize.

Here's my code:

```
import * as d3 from "d3";
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import styled, {ThemeContext} from "styled-components"

const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid ${({theme}) => theme.colors.primaryBlack};
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0.5px 0.5px 3.5px ${props => props.theme.colors.primaryBlack};
`

const SVGContainer = styled.svg`
  display: block;  
  width: 23em;
  height: 20em;
`

const Gauge = ({percent}) => {

  const theme = useContext(ThemeContext)
  const d3Ref = useRef(null)
  const createArc = d3.arc()
    .innerRadius(110)
    .outerRadius(140)
    .startAngle((-2/3)*Math.PI)

  const arcTween = newAngle => {
    return d => {
        const interpolate = d3.interpolate(d.endAngle, newAngle)
        return t => {
          d.endAngle = interpolate(t)
          return createArc(d)
        }
    }
  }

  const draw = () => {
    const d3Container = d3.select(d3Ref.current)

    // Refresh the container, remove old drawings
    const container = d3Container.append("g").style("transform", "translate(50%, 60%)")

    // Create the 100% custom arc for background
    container.append("path")
        .datum({endAngle: (2/3)*Math.PI})
        .style("fill", "#F2F2F2")
        .attr("d", createArc)

    // Create the progress custom arc for background
    const progress = container.append("path")
        .datum({endAngle: (-2/3)*Math.PI})
        .style("fill", "#4ABDAC")
        .attr("d", createArc)

    container.append("text")
        .style("font-size", "6.2rem")
        .style("font-weight", "900")
        .style("font-family", "Lato")
        .style("transform", "translate(0%, 7%)")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(`${percent}`)

    container.append("text")
        .style("font-size", "1.2rem")
        .style("font-family", "Lato")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .style("transform", "translate(0%, 15%)")
        .text("Looking good!")

    container.append("text")
        .style("font-size", "1.2rem")
        .style("font-family", "Lato")
        .style("fill", "#4ABDAC")
        .style("transform", "translate(0%, -20%)")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("↑ 5 pts")

    progress.transition().duration(2000).attrTween("d", arcTween(((2/3)*Math.PI)*(((2*percent)/100)-1)))
    d3Container.exit().remove()
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if(d3Ref.current){
      draw()
    }
  }, [d3Ref.current])

  useEffect(() => {
    if(typeof window !== undefined){
      window.addEventListener("resize", draw)
    }

    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", null)
  }, [])

  return (
    <Container theme={theme}>
      <SVGContainer ref={d3Ref} /> 
    </Container>
  )
}

export default Gauge
```

The biggest problem I'm having is the fact that d3 just keeps on appending which lead me to believe that `.exit().remove` is not working or am I just missing some sort of React knowledge here which leads to this behavior.

Any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much trial and error,

It seems I need to manually remove the g element through D3. 
I added, `d3.select("g").remove()` before each draw.